# Standard layout and inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the reason that the second class is not standard layout? (Visual Studio C++)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A
{
    int i;
};

struct B : public A
{
};

std::cout << "is_standard_layout<B> == "
          << std::boolalpha
          << std::is_standard_layout<B>::value // gives false
          << std::endl;
```

Comment: It seems Visual Studio 10 just do not support classes like is_standard_layout yet. GCC 4.6 works.

Comment: what std::is_standard_layout<> is supposed to do ? i haven't found very much documentation about this feature.

Comment: @Stephane: It's a metamethod that returns whether a class is standard layout. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Modification_to_the_definition_of_plain_old_data) has a thorough discussion of what that means.

Comment: @mazatwork, please accept the answer below or explain why it isn't adequate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accorting to [this](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport) MSVC supports built-in type traits since version 8 but [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) seems to say that you need version 11.

Section [9.7](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) defines a standard-layout class as a class that:

> - has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
> - has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1),
> - has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static data members,
> - has no non-standard-layout base classes,
> - either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members, and
> - has no base classes of the same type as the ﬁrst non-static data member.

There's [some explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160901/why-is-c11s-pod-standard-layout-definition-the-way-it-is).