# Wrapping C++ in C: Derived to base conversions

Tags: c++, c, oop, standard-layout

I am wrapping a simple C++ inheritance hierarchy into "object-oriented" C.  I'm trying to figure out if there any gotchas in treating the pointers to C++ objects as pointers to opaque C structs.  In particular, under what circumstances would the derived-to-base conversion cause problems?

The classes themselves are relatively complex, but the hierarchy is shallow and uses single-inheritance only:

```
// A base class with lots of important shared functionality
class Base {
    public:
    virtual void someOperation();
    // More operations...

    private:
    // Data...
};

// One of several derived classes
class FirstDerived: public Base {
    public:
    virtual void someOperation();
    // More operations...

    private:
    // More data...
};

// More derived classes of Base..
```

I am planning on exposing this to C clients via the following, fairly standard object-oriented C:

```
// An opaque pointers to the types
typedef struct base_t base_t;
typedef struct first_derived_t first_derived_t;

void base_some_operation(base_t* object) {
     Base* base = (Base*) object;
     base->someOperation();
}

first_derived_t* first_derived_create() {
     return (first_derived_t*) new FirstDerived();
}

void first_derived_destroy(first_derived_t* object) {
     FirstDerived* firstDerived = (FirstDerived*) object;
     delete firstDerived;
}
```

The C clients only pass around pointers to the underlying C++ objects and can only manipulate them via function calls.  So the client can finally do something like:

```
first_derived_t* object = first_derived_create();
base_some_operation((base_t*) object); // Note the derived-to-base cast here
...
```

and have the virtual call to FirstDerived::someOperation() succeed as expected.

These classes are not [standard-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160901/why-is-c11s-pod-standard-layout-definition-the-way-it-is) but do not use multiple or virtual inheritance.  Is this guaranteed to work?

Note that I have control over all the code (C++ and the C wrapper), if that matters.

Comment: Just use `void*` everywhere as your opaque type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// An opaque pointers to the types
typedef struct base_t base_t;
typedef struct first_derived_t first_derived_t;

// **********************//
// inside C++ stub only. //
// **********************//

// Ensures you always cast to Base* first, then to void*,
// then to stub type pointer.  This enforces that you'll
// get consistent a address in presence of inheritance.
template<typename T>
T * get_stub_pointer ( Base * object )
{
     return reinterpret_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(object));
}

// Recover (intermediate) Base* pointer from stub type.
Base * get_base_pointer ( void * object )
{
     return reinterpret_cast<Base*>(object);
}

// Get derived type pointer validating that it's actually
// the right type.  Returs null pointer if the type is
// invalid.  This ensures you can detect invalid use of
// the stub functions.
template<typename T>
T * get_derived_pointer ( void * object )
{
    return dynamic_cast<T*>(get_base_pointer(object));
}

// ***********************************//
// public C exports (stub interface). //
// ***********************************//

void base_some_operation(base_t* object)
{
     Base* base = get_base_pointer(object);
     base->someOperation();
}

first_derived_t* first_derived_create()
{
     return get_stub_pointer<first_derived_t>(new FirstDerived());
}

void first_derived_destroy(first_derived_t* object)
{
     FirstDerived * derived = get_derived_pointer<FirstDerived>(object);
     assert(derived != 0);

     delete firstDerived;
}
```

This means that you can always perform a cast such as the following.

```
first_derived_t* object = first_derived_create();
base_some_operation((base_t*) object);
```

This is safe because the `base_t*` pointer will be cast to `void*`, then to `Base*`.  This is one step less than what happened before.  Notice the order:

1. `FirstDerived*`
2. `Base*` (via implicit `static_cast<Base*>`)
3. `void*` (via `static_cast<void*>`)
4. `first_derived_t*` (via `reinterpret_cast<first_derived_t*>`)
5. `base_t*` (via `(base_t*)`, which is a C++-style `reinterpret_cast<base_t*>`)
6. `void*` (via implicit `static_cast<void*>`)
7. `Base*` (via `reinterpret_cast<Base*>`)

For calls that wrap a `FirstDerived` method, you get an extra cast:

1. `FirstDerived*` (via `dynamic_cast<FirstDerived*>`)

Comment: Nice, this seems to be both safe and clean, even in the face of future maintenance programmers who might not grok the whole end-to-end situation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly make a C interface to some C++ code. All you need is `extern "C"`, and I recommend a `void *` as your opaque data type:

```
// library.h, for C clients

typedef void * Handle;

extern "C" Handle create_foo();
extern "C" void destroy_foo(Handle);

extern "C" int magic_foo(Handle, char const *);
```

Then implement it in C++:

```
#include "library.h"
#include "foo.hpp"

Handle create_foo()
{
    Foo * p = nullptr;

    try { p = new Foo; }
    catch (...) { p = nullptr; }

    return p
}

void destroy_foo(Handle p)
{
    delete static_cast<Foo*>(p);
}

int magic_foo(Handle p, char const * s)
{
    Foo * const f = static_cast<Foo*>(p);

    try
    {
        f->prepare();
        return f->count_utf8_chars(s);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return -1;
        errno = E_FOO_BAR;
    }
}
```

Remember never to allow *any* exceptions to propagate through a calling C function!

Comment: I've done this before, and using `void*` is really problematic for type safety reasons on the client side (it's easy to pass *anything* as that argument).  Consider the windows API where a files and mutex objects are both identified by type `HANDLE`, meaning you can pass a file to `ReleaseMutex()`.  You can use an incomplete struct for each distinct type that should appear on the client side.  For example, `struct foo_t; typedef struct foo_t* foo_t;`.  Then, use `foo_t create_foo();` and `void destroy_foo(foo_t);`.

Comment: It adds a few nasty casts inside the C++-to-C stub implementation, but at least you get a "type safe" interface on the client side.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Thanks for the answer, but this is simpler than my case.  I'm worried about the cast from FirstDerived* to Base* via a C-style cast.  For example, if there was multiple inheritance involved, we'd be in trouble, no?  I'm looking for other gotchas...

Comment: @Adrian, I think you might want to consider updating your question to make this issue about Derived-to-Base conversions more explicit. This current answer doesn't involve any inheritance. I think there is no really safe way to allow any conversions in the C code; you might have to implement many functions such as `Base * getBaseFromDerived1(Derived1 *)` and `Base * getBaseFromDerived2(Derived2 *)` and so on.

Comment: @Adrian: Very simple: You must always cast the exact same thing back that you originally cast to `void *`. It really doesn't matter if and how the C++ classes are related; you must simply get the original type back, right on the nose.

Comment: Indeed, you might need to `static_cast<void*>(static_cast<Base*>(derived))` if necessary to ensure that the *exact* address is received.

Comment: @AndréCaron, yes, we can use those casts in the C++ code, but the question is about the casts in the C code. As far as I can see, we won't be able to safely allow any casts in the C code.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: yes you can.  Cast always cast *all* pointers to `Base*`.  In stubs for derived class functions, use a `static_cast` back to `Derived*` before calling the real function.  You can even use a `dynamic_cast` to make sure the client has not attempted something foolish.

Comment: @AndréCaron, maybe I'm stating the obvious, but the C code itself obviously cannot have `static_cast` in it. So, we're not wondering how to write the C++ code, we're trying to come up with a good interface to make available to the C code. The challenge is that in the C code there may be occasions when there are two variables of two different 'handle' types (derived1_t and base_t) which refer to the *same* object. We have to be very *careful* if the **C** code has any casts in it between these two handle types.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Re-read my last comment.  Doing what I suggested allows you to write the casts in the C code as in the example in your question.  Because you always cast to `Base*` before casting to the dummy C pointer type, casts to base classes are "safe" on the C side of things.

Comment: @AndréCaron, I see what you mean. Your idea is correct. Apologies. I think I dislike the idea of having a `Derived*` mean something different in the C code than it would mean in the C++ code. But that's just a style thing. My worry is that you might compile the C code with the C++ compiler and suddenly the `(Base*) derived1_pointer` casts break down.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: I added my idea as a answer.  You can check that out for possible flaws.

Answer (score 1):

This is the approach I've used in the past (perhaps as implied by Aaron's comment). Note that the *same* type names are used in both C and C++. Casts are all done in C++; this naturally represents good encapsulation irrespective of questions of legality. [Obviously you need `delete` methods as well.]
Note that to call `someOperation()` with a `Derived*`, an explicit upcast to `Base*` is required. *If* `Derived` does not provide any new methods such as `someOtherOperation`, then you do not need to expose `Derived*` to clients, and avoid the client side casts.

Header file:"BaseDerived.H"

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
    typedef struct Base Base;
    typedef struct Derived Derived;

    Derived* createDerived();
    Base* createBase();
    Base* upcastToBase(Derived* derived);
    Derived* tryDownCasttoDerived(Base* base);
    void someOperation(Base* base);
void someOtherOperation(Derived* derived);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Implementation: "BaseDerived.CPP"

```
#include "BaseDerived.H"
struct Base 
{
    virtual void someOperation()
    {
        std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
    }
};
struct Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void someOperation()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl;
    }
private:
};

Derived* createDerived()
{
    return new Derived;
}

Base* createBase()
{
    return new Base;
}

Base* upcastToBase(Derived* derived)
{
    return derived;
}

Derived* tryDownCasttoDerived(Base* base)
{
    return dynamic_cast<Derived*>(base);
}

void someOperation(Base* base)
{
    base->someOperation();
}

void someOperation(Derived* derived)
{
    derived->someOperation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think these two lines are the nub of the question:

```
first_derived_t* object = first_derived_create();
base_some_operation((base_t*) object); // Note the derived-to-base cast here
...
```

There is no really safe way to allow this in the C code. In C, such a cast never changes the raw integral value of the pointer, but sometimes C++ casts will do so and therefore you need a design that never has any casts within the C code.

Here is one (overly complex?) solution. First, decide on a policy that the C code will always strictly deal with a value which is effectively a `Base*` - this is a somewhat arbitrary policy to ensure consistency. This means that the C++ code will sometimes have to to a dynamic_cast, we'll come to that later.

(You can make the design work correctly with C code simply by using casts, as has been mentioned by others. But I'd would be worried that the compiler will allow all sorts of crazy casts, such as `(Derived1*) derived2_ptr` or even casts to types in a different class hierarchy. My goal here is to enforce the proper object-oriented *is-a* relationship within the C code.)

Then, the C handle classes could be something like

```
struct base_t_ptr {
    void * this_; // holds the Base pointer
};
typedef struct {
    struct base_t_ptr get_base;
} derived_t_ptr;
```

This should make it easy to use something like casts in a concise and safe way: Note how we pass in `object.get_base` in this code:

```
first_derived_t_ptr object = first_derived_create();
base_some_operation(object.get_base);
```

where the declaration of base_some_operation is

```
extern "C" base_some_operation(struct base_t_ptr);
```

This will be quite type safe, as you won't be able to pass a derived1_t_ptr to this function without going via the `.get_base` data member. It will also help your C code to know a little about the types and which conversions are valid - you don't want to accidentally convert Derived1 to Derived2.

Then, when implementing the **non-virtual** methods defined only in a derived class, you'll need something like:

```
extern "C" void derived1_nonvirtual_operation(struct derived1_t_ptr); // The C-style interface. Type safe.

void derived1_nonvirtual_operation(struct derived1_t_ptr d) {
    // we *know* this refers to a Derived1 type, so we can trust these casts:
    Base * bp = reinterpret_cast<Base*>(d.get_base.this_);
    Derived1 *this_ = dynamic_cast<Derived1*>;
    this_ -> some_operation();
}
```