# How is is_standard_layout useful?

Tags: c++, c++11, standard-layout

From what I understand, standard layout allows three things:

- Empty base class optimization
- Backwards compatibility with C with certain pointer casts
- Use of offsetof

Now, included in the library is the `is_standard_layout` predicate metafunction, but I can't see much use for it in generic code as those C features I listed above seem extremely rare to need checking in generic code. The only thing I can think of is using it inside `static_assert`, but that is only to make code more robust and isn't required.

How is `is_standard_layout` useful? Are there any things which would be impossible without it, thus requiring it in the standard library?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with making code more robust.

Answer (score 5):

### General response

It is a way of validating assumptions.  You wouldn't want to write code that assumes standard layout if that wasn't the case.

C++11 provides a bunch of utilities like this.  They are particularly valuable for writing generic code (templates) where you would otherwise have to trust the client code to not make any mistakes.

---

### Notes specific to `is_standard_layout`

It looks to me like the (pseudo code) definition of `is_pod` would roughly be...

```
// note: applied recursively to all members
bool is_pod(T) { return is_standard_layout(T) && is_trivial(T); }
```

So, you need to know `is_standard_layout` in order to implement `is_pod`.  Given that, we might as well expose `is_standard_layout` as a tool available to library developers.  Also of note: if you have a use-case for `is_pod`, you might want to consider the possibility that `is_standard_layout` might actually be a better (more accurate) choice in that case, since POD is essentially a subset of standard layout.

I get the feeling that they added every conceivable variant of type evaluation, regardless of any obvious value, just in case someone might encounter a need sometime before the next standard comes out.  I doubt if piling on these "extra" type properties adds a significant additional burden to compiler developers.

There is a nice discussion of standard layout here: [Why is C++11's POD "standard layout" definition the way it is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160901/why-is-c11s-pod-standard-layout-definition-the-way-it-is)
There is also a lot of good detail at cppreference.com: [Non-static data members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members)

Comment: *"You wouldn't want to write code that assumes standard layout"* But what type of generic code *assumes* standard layout? I've had uses for `is_pod` and `is_trivial` before, but never `is_standard_layout`.