# Strict aliasing char* to a wider type without undefined behavior

Tags: c++

I'm confused about whether or not this is a strict aliasing violation or invokes undefined behavior. Multiple people have told me it's not a violation and that there is no UB, but from reading the C++ spec it sounds like doing *anything* that dereferences a type-casted pointer (unless it was just cv-casted or casted to a compatible type or char) is UB.

```
#define SWAP(x) (((x) << 8) | ((x) >> 8)))

char* foo(char* data, size_t len16) {
  int align = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(data) % sizeof(uint16_t);
  if (align == 0) {
    uint16_t* data16 = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(data);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len16; i++) {
      data16[i] = SWAP(data16[i]);
    }
  } else {
    throw "Unaligned";
  }

  return data;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/DIXtJX

(This is a slightly contrived example; in reality `SWAP` may be a third-party function that requires a `uint16_t`.)

Is the story changed because we've checked alignment, are confident about the size of the types and don't care about endianness? The remaining concern would, I guess, be dead code elimination by the optimizer.

If this is illegal, how would you efficiently interpret a `char` buffer (e.g. from a file) as its intended type (e.g. `int16`s)? I'm familiar with casting through a union, but I don't really see how that's any different (see [casting through a union(1)](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html), aside from telling the compiler that it cannot do dead code elimination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Multiple people have told me it's not a violation and that there is no UB

Those people are wrong. This code:

```
uint16_t* data16 = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(data);
```

is defined behavior if, *and only if*, there is an object of type `uint16_t` at `data`. That is, if I called your foo like:

```
uint16_t p = 42;
foo(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&p), 2); // now, we're ok
```

or:

```
char data[64];
new (data) uint16_t{42};
foo(data, 2); // also ok, though with C++17 you'll have to use std::launder
```

But otherwise, it's UB. The non-UB way to do this would be:

```
uint16_t data16;
memcpy(&data16, data, sizeof(data16));
```

which many compilers will treat as a `reinterpret_cast`.

---

That said, an enormous amount of networking code does what you are doing, and there would be <strike>riots in the streets</strike> many angry messages posted on forums if compilers optimized this code in a way that caused it to not do what you want it to.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply. Re: the non-UB way, it looks like g++ indeed treats that like a `reinterpret_cast` for -Os, -O1 and -O2, but that method seems to prevent loop unrolling with -O3. https://godbolt.org/g/KHwOXi (Not tested if that's an actual deopt though.)

Answer (score 2):

> doing *anything* that dereferences a type-casted pointer (unless it was just cv-casted or casted to a compatible type or char) is UB.

That is not correct.

Any pointer can be cast to `char*` and `void*` and back. It is UB only when the original pointer is of a different type than the pointer type used when dereferencing the pointer. There are exceptions to even that. See [Struct alignment and type reinterpretation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599219/struct-alignment-and-type-reinterpretation) for an example.

Comment: Right, okay, but if the original pointer is a `char*` then it cannot be `reinterpret_cast`ed to e.g. a `uint16_t`? Or can we say the "original pointer" was a `uint16_t` because e.g. another executable wrote `uint16_t`s?

Comment: @ZachB, are you talking about data received over a network or read from a file?

Comment: Either, but we know the endianness, if that's what you're getting at.

Comment: @ZachB, that's correct. If data is received or read with the same endianness, than you should be good.