# Custom arguments to std::set comparison function

Tags: c++, parameters, stl, set, runtime

I know how to pass a regular comparison class or function to set::set<>.

I am writing some test code and I want to emulate some C libraries using STL's std::set and I want to be able to pass a C callback to the comparison object so a different comparison takes place.

I have the following theoretical code:

```
struct MyClass
{
    int a;
};

typedef bool (*user_callback_t)(void *, void *);
class MyComparison
{
private:
    user_callback_t cb = nullptr;
public:
    MyComparison(user_callback_t cb): cb(cb) { }
    MyComparison() {}
    bool operator()(const MyClass &a, const MyClass &b) const
    {
        return cb((void *)&a, (void *)&b);
    }
};

int f1()
{
    auto cmp = [](void *a, void *b) -> bool
    {
        return *(int *)a < *(int *)b;
    };

    MyComparison mycmp(cmp);

    std::set<MyClass, MyComparison> m1;

    m1.insert({ 1 });
    m1.insert({ 2 });
    m1.insert({ 3 });

    return 0;
};
```

Now notice how I can do:

```
   std::set<MyClass, MyComparison> m1;
```

But I cannot, somehow, instantiate a MyComparison object, pass it "cmp" and then use that initialize comparison object with that specific set.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Why can't you? Btw, you're comparing integers when you have a container of `MyClass`. That's UB.

Comment: @krzaq See first answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160901/why-is-c11s-pod-standard-layout-definition-the-way-it-is - but yes, why can't you?

Comment: Maybe [read some docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set).

Comment: That answer is about casting pointer to T to a pointer to U and back to T. That's well-defined indeed. Dereferencing it `MyClass*` as `int*` is undefined as far as my understanding of [basic.lval]/10 from N4140 goes.

Comment: According to the manual you can pass the comparator to the `std::set` constructor: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set

Comment: Why is everybody beating on this question so much? Ordinarily you don't have to pass anything to the constructor, so it's not intuitively obvious that that's the solution to the question. Just answer it instead of making snide remarks!

Answer (score 3):

Your assertion that you can't pass a `MyComparison` instance to `std::set` for it to use it is wrong. There is a constructor for `std::set` expecting just that (in C++11):

```
explicit set( const Compare& comp = Compare(),
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

So your `MyComparison` can be passed as first argument.

```
std::set<MyClass, MyComparison> m1(mycmp);
```

If you don't have C++11 or newer available, then this constructor overload is non-existing and you need to use another one:

```
template< class InputIt >
set( InputIt first, InputIt last,
     const Compare& comp = Compare(),
     const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

This one however expects an interator range in the first two arguments. Since we don't actually want to construct from a range, they need to be dummies. You could do someting like:

```
std::vector<int> dummy;
std::set<MyClass, MyComparison> m1(dummy.begin(), dummy.end(), mycomp);
```

`dummy` will not be used afterwards. I am not sure whether there is a nicer solution besides implementing a dummy iterator class.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set for full reference on constructors of `std::set`.