# Is it possible to get a pointer to one subobject via a pointer to a different, unreleated subobject?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, c++17, offsetof

Look at this simple code:

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

void something(int *);

int main() {
    Point p{1, 2};

    something(&p.x);

    return p.y;
}
```

I expect, that `main`'s return value can be optimized to `return 2;`, as `something` doesn't have access to `p.y`, it only gets a pointer to `p.x`.

But, none of the major compilers optimize the return value of `main` to `2`. [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/XrJi4u).

Is there something in the standard, which allows `something` to modify `p.y`, if we only give access to `p.x`? If yes, does this depend on whether `Point` has standard layout?

What if I use `something(&p.y);`, and `return p.x;` instead?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote and the flag. This is perfectly reasonable question to me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803202/where-in-the-c-standard-is-the-memory-layout-of-objects-documented "Implementation alignment requirements might cause two adjacent members not to be allocated immediately after each other"

Comment: @alterigel: this shouldn't matter, as we can use `offsetof`. But I'm not sure that we can actually get a pointer to `p.y` from `p.x`, with the new pointer semantic rules of C++17. `std::launder` cannot be used, as a pointer to `p.x` can only reach `p.x`. So even if I could move the pointer to the correct location, maybe that pointer won't point to the object of `p.y`.

Comment: If you change it to `void something(int * x) { *(x+1) = 6; }` it optimizes the return value to a fixed `6`, so the compiler at least sees that as a valid option to do.

Comment: @zereges, didn't downvote, but almost did. The question is very hard to parse. I believe the OP is asking: "why can't the compiler realize the something() function will not modify p.y ?" If the OP asked that directly, there'd be less downvotes.

Comment: @geza On a flat addressing arch, when a ptr is just a number, you technically don't even need `std::launder` because ptr are trivial type and a correct bit pattern is enough! But f.ex. the C committee made up an anti ptr guessing rule in a DR, as allowing users to come up with correct bit patterns of ptr by any means was too lax obviously.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is perfectly well-defined:

```
void something(int *x) {
    reinterpret_cast<Point*>(x)->y = 42;
}
```

The `Point` object (`p`) and its `x` member are pointer-interconvertible, from [[basic.compound]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4):

> Two objects *a* and *b* are *pointer-interconvertible* if:
>
> - [...]
> - one is a standard-layout class object and the other is the first non-static data member of that object, or, if the object has no non-static data members, any base class subobject of that object ([class.mem]), or:
> - [...]
>
> If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same address, and it is possible to obtain a pointer to one from a pointer to the other via a `reinterpret_­cast`.

That `reinterpret_cast<Point*>(x)` is valid and does end up with a pointer that points to `p`. Hence, modifying it directly is fine. As you can see, the standard-layout part and the first non-static data member part are significant.

---

Although it's not like the compilers in question optimize out the extra load if you pass a pointer to `p.y` in and return `p.x` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that I left a hole in my question. So, if I used `something(&p.y); return p.x;`, then it is clearly a missed optimization?

Comment: @geza For some definition of "clearly". There almost certainly exists a lot of code that does things like this that such an optimization would break.

Comment: @geza Technically, yes, it would be a missed optimization then, but I don't think major compilers, at this time, are prepared to break all the existing code that uses `offsetof`.

Comment: Doesn't that violate the strict-aliasing rule? Or is that a C-only rule?

Comment: @sturcotte06 it does not because of *If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same address, and it is possible to obtain a pointer to one from a pointer to the other via a reinterpret_­cast.*

Comment: Am I missing something here?  the cast changes the pointer to `p.x` into a pointer to `Point`, but nonetheless, it's still pointing _at_ the same memory location?  That would mean this only works because `x` is the first member, and thus exists at the same memory location as the 'parent' object `Point p`?  So if we were to pass `&p.y` into the function, we would get different behaviour (undefined?)

Comment: Congrats for 200k!