# C++: How to make the compiler optimize memory access in case when a pointer of a member variable is passed elsewhere

Tags: c++, optimization, member-variables, offsetof

[edit: Here is the motivation: passing a pointer of a variable to an external function may accidentally break some optimization for "adjacent" variables, because of the possibility to get pointers to the adjacent variables calculated from the original pointer by the external function. The following is the original post, in which the `volatile` is to simulate an external function inaccessible to the current compiler unit, e.g. virtual function call, closed source library function, etc.]

I wondered if the `return t.a;` in the following code would be optimized to `return 0;`.

```cpp
//revision 1
struct T
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

void f_(int * p)
{
    *p = 1;
}
auto volatile f = f_;

int main()
{
    T t;
    t.a = 0;
    t.b = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        f(&t.b);
    }
    return t.a;
}
```

Well [it's not](https://godbolt.org/z/KrrYcx).
Fair enough because the code in function `f` may use `offsetof` to acquire a pointer to `t` then change `t.a`.
So it's not safe to optimize the load of `t.a` away.

[edit: At a second thought, `offsetof` is not enough here. We need `container_of`, which there seems no way to implement in standard C++.]

But `offsetof` cannot be used on non-standard-layout types. So I tried the following code:

```cpp
//revision 2
#include <type_traits>

struct T
{
private:
    char dummy = 0;
public:
    int a;
    int b;
};
static_assert(!std::is_standard_layout_v<T>);

void f_(int * p)
{
    *p = 1;
}
auto volatile f = f_;

int main()
{
    T t;
    t.a = 0;
    t.b = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        f(&t.b);
    }
    return t.a;
}
```

Unfortunately it's still not working.

My questions are:

- whether it's safe to optimize the load of `t.a` away in the above case (revision 2)
- if it's not, is there some arrangement in existence/proposal to make it possible? (e.g. making `T` a more special type, or some attribute specifier for member `b` in `T`)

P.S. The following code is optimized for `return t.a;`, but the yielded code for the loop is a bit inefficient.
And still, the temporary variable juggling is cumbersome.

```cpp
//revision 3
struct T
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

void f_(int * p)
{
    *p = 1;
}
auto volatile f = f_;

int main()
{
    T t;
    t.a = 0;
    t.b = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        int b = t.b;
        f(&b);
        t.b = b;
    }
    return t.a;
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. It seems like you try your best to _not_ get the code optimized yet wonder how to make the compiler optimize it. Perhaps it'd be better if you instead asked how to perform a specific task to not risk having this question placed in the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) category.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using `volatile` as it's correct use in C++ is very restricted ?  This feels like an XY-Problem.

Comment: By marking `f` as volatile, you've told the compiler that `f` may be changed by some code that is not visible to the compiler. In the first case, the compiler needs to allow for the possibility `f()` may change arbitrarily in the loop, and do different things - such as change `t.a` on any loop iteration. It would be quite feasible for `f` to change so `f()` does `*(p-1) = 42` as that is a perfectly well-defined way of modifying `t.a` if passed `&t.b` since `t.a` and `t.b` are in the same object (data struct).  Similar discussion for your revisions.

Comment: @TedLyngmo see my "motivation" edit.

Comment: @RichardCritten see my "motivation" edit.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `offsetof` to reach `T::a` from `T::b` is illegitimate, since there is no object [pointer-interconvertible](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4) with `T::b` from which `T::a` can be reached. In the other direction it is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57979009/is-it-possible-to-get-a-pointer-to-one-subobject-via-a-pointer-to-a-different-u) to reach `T::b` from `T::a`, since the latter is pointer-interconvertible with `T`. Contra Peter in comments (and despite the existence of [`container_of`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832301/understanding-container-of-macro-in-the-linux-kernel) macro in e.g. Linux kernel), `&t.b - 1` does not yield a pointer to `t.a`, since `T::b` and `T::a` are not pointer-interconvertible.

Note that given a pointer to `T::a` you would still need to use [`std::launder`](https://eel.is/c++draft/ptr.launder#4) to access `T::b`:

```
auto p = &t.a;
std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(p))->b = 1;
```

So a sufficiently aggressive compiler would indeed be able to conclude that no replacement `f` could access `t.a` given a pointer to `t.b`. However, it appears that no mainstream compiler performs this optimization at this time.

Comment: I think no compiler would actively do this kind of optimization because of the widely used `container_of` macro, be it conforming or not. Any (even potential) `__container_of` alike compiler extension would prohibit it. So we need something like `[[no_outer_cast]]` attribute to explicitly allow it.