# Confused about std::is_standard_layout type trait

Tags: c++, c++11

[Standard-layout class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes#Standard-layout_class) describes a standard layout class that:

> 1. has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
> 2. has no virtual functions and no virtual base classes,
> 3. has the same access control for all non-static data members,
> 4. has no non-standard-layout base classes,
> 5. has all non-static data members and bit-fields in the class and its base classes first declared in the same class, and
> 6. given the class as S, has no element of the set M(S) of types as a base class, where M(X) for a type X is defined as:
>
>    1. If X is a non-union class type with no (possibly inherited) non-static data members, the set M(X) is empty.
>    2. If X is a non-union class type whose first non-static data member has type X0 (where said member may be an anonymous union), the set M(X) consists of X0 and the elements of M(X0).
>    3. If X is a union type, the set M(X) is the union of all M(Ui) and the set containing all Ui, where each Ui is the type of the ith non-static data member of X.
>    4. If X is an array type with element type Xe, the set M(X) consists of Xe and the elements of M(Xe).
>    5. If X is a non-class, non-array type, the set M(X) is empty.

(numbered for convivence)

However, the following fails:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
    int a;
};
struct B : A {
    int b;
};

static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<A>::value, "not standard layout"); // succeeds
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<B>::value, "not standard layout"); // fails
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qqh1EEv68)</kbd>

I see that 1-4 are true, so is one of points under 5 false?  I find the points under 5 a little confusing.

Comment: I'm confused about what the requirement "has all non-static data members and bit-fields in the class and its base classes first declared in the same class" means

Comment: Note that you are missing a point: number 6 starts with "given the class as S"...

Comment: @Nelfeal, it was there, I just forgot to separate the line into two lines.  Thx for pointing it out.

Comment: I made a couple edits to that cppreference page for human readability, let's see if they stick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cppreference description is a little confusing.

The [standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) (search "standard-layout class is") says:

> A standard-layout class is a class that:
>
> - has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
> - has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1),
> - has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static data members,
> - has no non-standard-layout base classes,
> - **either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members**, and
> - has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member.

You can see from the part I emphasized that a class with a non-static data member and a base class that itself has a non-static data member is not standard-layout.

I suspect this point is described as follows in cppreference:

> has all non-static data members and bit-fields in the class and its base classes first declared in the same class

The point is that you must be able to cast the address of a standard-layout class object to a pointer to its first member, and back. It boils down to compatibility between C++ and C.

See also: [Why is C++11's POD "standard layout" definition the way it is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160901/why-is-c11s-pod-standard-layout-definition-the-way-it-is).

Comment: Doesn't the following [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G6oaohGfe) have at most 1 base class with non-static data members?

Comment: @Adrian Indeed it has *at most one base class with non-static data members*, but it doesn't have *no non-static data members in the most derived class*. The complete sentence basically says "only one class in the inheritance hierarchy can have non-static data members".

Comment: Ugh!  The wording is just horrible. :(

Comment: @Adrian Well yes, standardese must formal, precise, consistant, complete, ... Just like legalese: that's partly why lawyers exist.

Comment: Still, saying that only one class in the hierarchy can have non-static data members is far clearer and shouldn't be misinterpreted. even in a legalize perspective.

Comment: @Adrian Except, 0 can have members and you are also fine.  Your definition requires defining "heirarchy", which I suspect the standard does not.